# Do client libraries normally implement retry mechanisms?

Tags: python, retry-logic

I noticed that [`googleapiclient.discovery.build()`](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/epy/googleapiclient.discovery-pysrc.html#build) calls a function that has `num_retries` as a field, so I think that means I  don't have to implement retries & error handling when calling a function that takes care of that for me; is this the correct assumption in these scenarios?

Comment: Most likely not every library is doing it in the same way.